# Зависимость данных в элементах html. ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

На странице есть два выпадающих списка - отделы и сотрудники. Нужно, чтобы во втором списке были сотрудники только того отдела, который выбран в первом списке. Как это сделать, если контейнеры готовятся заранее? Или как можно вытянуть выбранное значение выпадающего списка, чтобы использовать это значение для индексации?

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ResponsibleDepartmentId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-5">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ResponsibleDepartment, (SelectList)ViewBag.DepartmentId, "", new { @class = "form-control selectize"})
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ResponsibleEmployeeId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-5">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ResponsibleEmployeeId, (SelectList)ViewBag.CreatorId , new { @class = "form-control selectize" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ну пусть вначале у тебя будет один список. При выборе кого-то в первом списке делается запрос, и пусть ответ тебе вёрстку со значениями рисует

Comment: Можно подробнее?

Comment: На странице дропбокс со значениями. Выбираешь в нём значение, у этого значения берётся идентификатор какой-нибудь и отправляется в обработчик события "select" у дропбокса. В событии делается запрос по идентификатору, возвращаются значения, связанные с ним, и потом просто вёрсткой рисуется ещё один дропбокс уже с подходящими значениями и выводится в блок. Как-то так.

Comment: При выборе значения делай ajax запрос на сервер, выбираешь нужных сотрудников, и добавляешь их во второй выпадающий список. Перед добавлением, второй список не забудь отчистить от старых данных.

Comment: Попробуйте вот так https://metanit.com/sharp/articles/mvc/17.php